# how to delete a null queue(i.e without queue name ) in activemq 5.8.0?

Tags: activemq-classic

How to delete a null queue(i.e without queue name ) in activemq 5.8.0 ?

I have a problem with null queue when I delete the null queue with the help of delete button in active 5.8.0 console then throws some Error as shown below.

> i.e Error!
>
> Exception occurred while processing this request, check the log for
>   more information!
>
> What do you want to do next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we ran into this issue recently and I logged this ticket on it: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-5211

we are using mkahadb (configured to use a separate directory per destination) and were able to simply delete the corresponding directory (/data//kaha/queue#3a#2f#2f) and restart AMQ...

otherwise, try JMX or you'll need to wipe out the entire message store and start over as Tim suggested...

Answer (score 1):

There were some issues around creation of Queues with blank names in earlier releases.  I'm not sure that you will be successful in deleting the Queue without simply deleting all that KahaDB files and starting over.

One thing to try would be to use JConsole to connect to the broker and invoking the remove operation on the Queue MBean.

Comment: Using JConsole worked fine for me, just invoke the removeQueue with empty value field.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code I wrote a while back to deal with a similar problem.  It connects using JMX and removes any empty queues that have never been used.

```
import javax.management.JMX;
import javax.management.MBeanServerConnection;
import javax.management.ObjectName;
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnector;
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory;
import javax.management.remote.JMXServiceURL;

import org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.BrokerViewMBean;
import org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.QueueViewMBean;

public class CleanQueues {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length != 1 && args.length != 2) {
            System.out.println("Usage: CleanQueues host [port]");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        String host = args[0];
        String port = "1099";
        if (args.length == 2) {
            port = args[2];
        }
        JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://"+host+":"+port+"/jmxrmi");
        JMXConnector jmxc = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url, null);
        MBeanServerConnection connection = jmxc.getMBeanServerConnection();
        ObjectName broker = null;
        for (ObjectName objectName : connection.queryNames(new ObjectName("org.apache.activemq:BrokerName=*,Type=Broker"),null)) {
            broker = objectName;
        }
        if (broker == null) {
            System.out.println("Could not find broker name.");
            System.exit(2);
        }
        BrokerViewMBean proxy = JMX.newMBeanProxy(connection, broker, BrokerViewMBean.class);

        for (ObjectName n : proxy.getQueues()) {
            QueueViewMBean q = JMX.newMBeanProxy(connection, n, QueueViewMBean.class);
            if (q.getDispatchCount() == 0 && q.getConsumerCount() == 0) {
                System.out.println("Removing queue: "+q.getName());
                proxy.removeQueue(q.getName());
            }
        }
    }
}
```